# Excel Drop Down Box with Formula

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have an excel with a drop down box whose list has 3 cells. One of these cells contain a formula. The problem is this formula is dependent on data in another cell and when this data changes the calculated value changes. The value is automatically update in the list where it was chosen from but I will manually have to go back to the drop down box and change it. How can I have the value be updated automatically. Willing to look at a VBA solution if need be

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into the worksheet module. It assumes that the cell with validation applied is G9, and the second option of the list is the formula.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "G9" Then
        If Target.HasFormula Then Exit Sub 'or else infinite loop
        Dim ListRange As Range
        Dim FoundIdx As Variant
        Set ListRange = Me.Evaluate(Me.Range("G9").Validation.Formula1)
        FoundIdx = Application.Match(Target.Value, ListRange, 0)
        If Not IsError(FoundIdx) Then
            If FoundIdx = 2 Then
                Target.Formula = ListRange(2).Formula
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this will *not* work if the formula might have the same value as any of the other options!

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't reproduce your issue. Here is what I did:

- Populate 2 cells with a random value and a third cell with a formula (columns B3, B4, B5)
- Define a Name Range with these 3 cells called it Options
- Create a drop down using Insert/Form Controls/Combo Box
- Set the input range of the drop down to Options
- Change the cells value to get the formula give different results and the new values are reflected on the Options list and the Drop Down.

Is this what you are doing?